# Insert values in pandas dataframe using list values corresponding to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
id    val    size
1      100
2      500
3      300
```

i have a nested list L = [[300,20],[100,45],[500,12]]

I want to fill my dataframe with 2nd element in my sublist, corresponding to that column value.

i.e my final dataframe should look like

```
id    val    size
1      100   45
2      500   12
3      300   20
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First initialise a mapping:

```
In [132]: mapping = dict([[300,20],[100,45],[500,12]]); mapping
Out[132]: {100: 45, 300: 20, 500: 12}
```

Now, you can use either `df.replace` or `df.map`.

---

**Option 1**

Using `df.replace`:

```
In [137]: df['size'] = df.val.replace(mapping)

In [138]: df
Out[138]: 
   id  val  size
0   1  100    45
1   2  500    12
2   3  300    20
```

---

**Option 2**

Using `df.map`:

```
In [140]: df['size'] = df.val.map(mapping)

In [141]: df
Out[141]: 
   id  val  size
0   1  100    45
1   2  500    12
2   3  300    20
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `merge`

```
In [1417]: df.merge(pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['val', 'size']), on='val')
Out[1417]:
   id  val  size
0   1  100    45
1   2  500    12
2   3  300    20
```